# How to find the transfer function of this first order active filter?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, filter, transfer-function

Going through [Design with Operational Amplifiers and Analog Integrated Cricuits](http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/franco/), in Chapter 3, problem 3.4 I am asked:

> The circuit of Fig. P3.4 is a noninverting differentiator.
>
> - (a) Derive its transfer function.
> - (b) Specify component values for a unity-gain frequency of 100 Hz.
>
> [image]

---

I know that for a differentiator such as this, `H(s) = -RCs`

[image]

and for example, a resistor and capacitor in parallel, the impedance Z1 is equal to `R/RCs +1`.

The closest example I could find was that of a Deboo integrator, whose transfer function is `H(s) = 1/RCs`.

[image]

I am still struggling to understand how to extract the transfer function for Figure3.4. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the differentiator relevant? It has a capacitor between input and inverting input and thus different behavior. Trying to find "the closest" circuit for which you know the transfer functions is a stupid approach as only one component needs to be different for a completely different behavior. What you need to do is to learn the **method** that is used to derive the transfer function. That is called **circuit analysis** and is explained in many textbooks. I suggest you start simple, derive the transfer function of the differentiator first and work your way up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nothing than the equations of feedback theory for opamps.

The general form for the closed-loop gain is

**Acl=Hf * Aol/(1+Hr * Aol)**

which simplifies for infinite openloop gain Aol to

**Acl=Hf/Hr.**

Here, the function Hf is the forward damping and Hr is the feedback function. Both are defined as follows:

**Hf=Vd/Vin for Vout=0** (grounded) with Vd=diff. voltage at the opamp input nodes.

**Hr=Vd/Vout for Vin=0**

This way, the problem is reduced to simple voltage dividers.

**Alternative**(Edit): Perhaps the following method is easier to understand:

For an ideal opamp we have Vd=Vp-Vn=0 >>>>**Vp=Vn**

1) It easy to find Vn=f(Vout)

2) Vp=f(Vin, Vout) needs application of the superposition rule.

From both equations it shouldn`t be a problem to isolate Acl=Vout/Vin